# How can I increase the 128 character limit of a menu path?

Tags: 6, navigation

I know there are patches to core, but they were never backported to Drupal 6 from what I can tell.

- [Increasing path length to 255 chars](http://drupal.org/node/288946)
- [Menu path length is limited by the UI to 128 characters](http://drupal.org/node/1237290)

How can this be overridden in a theme?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix this by using [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and override the default `maxlength` for the input field, and then change the field in the db to `varchar(255)` if it isn't already.

Another option would be to use a token value for the path and change the value on output using [`theme_menu_item()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_item/6).

Perhaps the best option after all would be the [Custom Tokens](http://drupal.org/project/token_custom) module. I haven't tried it so I can't say if it works.

The downside with tokens is that you would have to make one token per URL, or possibly use a part of the URL if it's generally the same.

Comment: Keep in mind that, if you alter the schema of a table defined from another module, you need to also implement `hook_schema_alter()`.